# Service in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Service: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ServiceSpec.spec.ports of type []v1.Service

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When running `kubectl apply -f ./sftest.yml`, I get the following  error:

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "./sftest.yaml": Service in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Service: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ServiceSpec.spec.ports of type []v1.ServicePort

This happens when I'm trying to apply yaml,
Thats my first time working with k8s, this is the final problem that i cant solve

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-sf
  labels:
    app: nginx-sf
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-sf-pod
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-sf-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        name: 'nginx-sf-container'
        image: 'nginx:1.21.1-alpine'
        ports:
          containerPort: 80
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Hello Kubernetes from the Deployment! && sleep 3600']
        volumeMounts:
          name: config-volume
          mountPath: '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
        volumeMounts:
          name: auth_basic
          mountPath: '/etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd'
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
          name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: nginx.conf
          name: auth_basic
          secret:
            secretName: auth-basic

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sf-webserver
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-sf
  ports:
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

Answer (score 4):

In your Service manifest, the value of `ports` needs to be an *array*, not a mapping; see the example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service). That would look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sf-webserver
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-sf
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

---

You may have another problem; it's unclear from your question. If you have both your Deployment and the Service contained in the same file `sftest.yml`, then you need to put a YAML document separator (`---`) between them:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-sf
  labels:
    app: nginx-sf
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-sf-pod
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-sf-pod
    spec:
      containers:
        name: 'nginx-sf-container'
        image: 'nginx:1.21.1-alpine'
        ports:
          containerPort: 80
        command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Hello Kubernetes from the Deployment! && sleep 3600']
        volumeMounts:
          name: config-volume
          mountPath: '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
        volumeMounts:
          name: auth_basic
          mountPath: '/etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd'
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
          name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: nginx.conf
          name: auth_basic
          secret:
            secretName: auth-basic
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sf-webserver
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-sf
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```